# ASP.NET: how to validate

Tags: asp.net, compare, validation

I have a simple ASP.NET (VB) page with a CompareValidator. I can check to ensure the value is numeric, but I have no idea how to check for the length (business rules require a 7 digit number). Existing code is below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicyNo" runat="server" 
                    BorderStyle="Ridge"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvCheckPolicy" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Must be a valid policy number" ControlToValidate="txtPolicyNo" 
                    Type="Integer" Operator="DataTypeCheck">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RangeValidator or RegularExpressionValidator

```
<asp:RangeValidator id="rvCheckPolicy"
   ControlToValidate="txtPolicyNo" 
   MinimumValue="1000000"
   MaximumValue="9999999"
   Type="Integer"
   EnableClientScript="false"
   ErrorMessage="Must be a valid policy number" 
   runat="server"/>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="revCheckPolicy" 
    ControlToValidate="txtPolicyNo" 
    ValidationExpression="\d{7}"
    ErrorMessage="Must be a valid policy number" 
    runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RegularExpressionValidator with a regex string like `"^\d{7}$"`. That will ensure you get a 7 digit number. You might have to combine that with a RequiredFieldValidator to make sure they enter *something*.

Comment: +1, regex can be used both in client side validation and server side validation. its more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

To Check business rules, the [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is normally used.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="invalid text"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

But if you only want to validate 7 digits, you can use `RegularExpressionValidator` with the validation expression: `ValidationExpression=^\d{7}$`